# How to get a fullscreen Rectangle with Qt5.2 using qml?

Tags: android, qt, fullscreen, qml

I am newer for coding andorid apps with Qt5.2 using qml,

I want to get a fullscreen app back ground Rectangle with different android device:

```
Rectangle {
    id:fullscreenbackground
    height: ?
    width: ?     
    ......
}
```

It seems height  or width should been defined explicit and can't use percentage to define.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To resize the top-level item to the view’s size, use [QQuickView::setResizeMode()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qquickview.html#resizeMode-prop):

```
view.setResizeMode(QQuickView::SizeRootObjectToView);
```

That overrides any width/height set on the top-level QML item. For non-top-level items use

```
anchors.fill: parent
```

On Android, setting the resize mode should suffice. On other platforms, you might have to explicitely show the view in fullscreen:

```
view.showFullscreen();
```

Answer (score 1):

What about doing it like this:

```
Rectangle {
    id:fullscreenbackground
    anchors.fill: parent
    ......
}
```

Comment: The  Retangle   i  wanna to get  is the top  level, so i  think the codes  anchors.fill: parent  your  pointed could't  get

Answer (score 0):

A simple one is here!

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.0

ApplicationWindow {
    id: root
    width: Screen.width
    height: Screen.height
    color: "black"
    flags: Qt.FramelessWindowHint

    Rectangle{
        id: fullScreenRectangle
        width: Screen.width
        height: Screen.height
        border.color: "red"
        border.width: 53
        z: 1
    }
}
```